# EF code-first: Sequence contains more than one matching element

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 code-first, and have a `User` class that needs to have incoming and outgoing connections to other users. A connection also has properties, so I also have a `Connections` class.

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // Other properties removed here to keep it simple

    [InverseProperty("SourceUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Connection> OutgoingConnections { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("DestUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Connection> IncomingConnections { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // Other properties removed here to keep it simple

    [InverseProperty("OutgoingConnections")]
    public User SourceUser { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("IncomingConnections")]
    public User DestUser { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when updating my database. Initially I didn't have the `InverseProperty` attributes, so I can understand why EF didn't know what to do in that case. The documentation sounds like these attributes are what I want though - but it's still not working. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding it though.

I want to end up with a `Users` table, and a `Connections` table where the `Connections` table has `ID`, `SourceUserID`, `DestUserID` (obviously with FK constraints).

Any ideas?

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied
>   to the target database. Applying explicit migrations:
>   [201411192045091_InitialCreate]. Applying explicit migration:
>   201411192045091_InitialCreate. System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Sequence contains more than one matching element    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass250.b__247(<>f__AnonymousType2b`2
>   <>h__TransparentIdentifier242)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata
>   source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator,
>   MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String
>   sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument
>   sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1
>   modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator
>   migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String
>   targetModelVersion)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument
>   model, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Sequence contains more than one matching element

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx have you read this article for code-First Inverse Attributes

Comment: Yes, that's where I heard about the InverseProperty I'm using. Perhaps I'm reading it incorrectly though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if using InverseProperties is a requirement but the relationships can be done this way if you have the flexibility to wire them up differently.

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Connection> OutgoingConnections { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Connection> IncomingConnections { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int SourcerId {get;set;}

    public int DestUserId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("SourcerId")]
    public User SourceUser { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("DestUserId")]
    public User DestUser { get; set; }
}
```

then you need to add configurations.  In my case to test this I did it in  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) in the context.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x=>x.IncomingConnections).WithRequired(x=>x.SourceUser).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.OutgoingConnections).WithRequired(x => x.DestUser).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! :) Nope, no requirement on InverseProperty. That's now working fine as per your example :)