# Code first : Sequence contains more than one matching element - multiple classes with multiple references

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, code-first

I'm getting the "Sequence contains more than one matching element" error message while attempting to run the "Add-Migration" command. I believe that the issue is stemming from the fact that I have multiple classes that have multiple references to a shared class.

```
class User {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
// other stuff removed for display purposes
    [InverseProperty("CreateUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> FooCreateUser { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ModifyUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> FooModifyUser { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("CreateUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> BarCreateUser { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ModifyUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> BarModifyUser { get; set; }
}

class Foo {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid FooId {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("FooCreateUser")]
    public User CreateUser {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("FooModifyUser")]
    public User ModifyUser {get; set;}
}

class Bar {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid BarId {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("BarCreateUser")]
    public User CreateUser {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("BarModifyUser")]
    public User ModifyUser {get; set;}
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Do I have to change the field names in the [Bar] and [Foo] database tables to be unique? 
i.e. change [Foo][CreateUser] to [Foo][Foo_CreateUser]?

I need to have a "CreateUser" and "ModifyUser" field on multiple database tables and it doesn't make any sense (from a database design perspective) to have all of those fields uniquely named.

How do I tell CodeFirst to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF code-first: Sequence contains more than one matching element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237374/ef-code-first-sequence-contains-more-than-one-matching-element)

Comment: Could you provide your stacktrace and the block of code that throws the exception? You shouldn't have any problems with reusing names/classes as you have them above. My first guess, without any other information, would be a problem with `ICollection<Foo>` and/or the items being added not being unique.